# In polars how do I name a column that is created using group_by and n_unique?

Tags: python, python-polars

I am trying to replace some pandas with polars. I am new to polars.

Original code:

```
return pd.DataFrame(
    data.groupby([list_of_fields]).size(),
    columns=["Count"],
).reset_index()
```

I am stuck on how to name the column "Count". So far I have tried:

```
return pl.DataFrame(data.groupby([list_of_fields]).n_unique( "Count"))
```

but this gives:

```
TypeError: n_unique() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

`n_unique` only seems to allow a name parameter when it is not attached to `groupby`. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproducible example? How many columns/fields are there in your DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html) in pandas counts the number of rows in each group.

In polars, this can be achieved by using [`pl.len`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.len.html). We start with some example data.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"],
})
```

```
shape: (6, 1)
┌───────┐
│ group │
│ ---   │
│ str   │
╞═══════╡
│ A     │
│ A     │
│ A     │
│ B     │
│ B     │
│ C     │
└───────┘
```

Now, using

```py
df.group_by("group", maintain_order=True).agg(pl.len().alias("Count"))
```

gives

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ Count │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ A     ┆ 3     │
│ B     ┆ 2     │
│ C     ┆ 1     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

Note that we've used [`pl.Expr.alias`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.alias.html) to rename the `pl.len()` expression in the `group_by` context.